# Como validar campos en procedimientos almacenados MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero que me recomienden la forma mas optima de validar los campos de una tabla al hacer un insert por procedimientos almacenados, cuando digo validar me refiero a que no se ingresen datos repetidos en campos que están definidos como únicos.

Mi pregunta surge ya que si intento hacer un insert repetido en un campo único el sistema me genera una alerta pero un poco fea y en ingles, lo que quiero es darle un mensaje bien claro al cliente de que es lo que realmente pasa cuando se intenta hacer un insert de ese tipo. Ejemplo (La categoría ya existe.) y no un error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'GRANOS' for key 'descripcion_UNIQUE'

Comment: ¿En qué gestor estás aplicando esto pues agregaste mysql, oracle y sql-server?

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta y que ésta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Como ya te dijeron, deberías indicar la etiqueta del motor para refinar la solución. Una posibilidad es que en vez de controlar el error antes  que ocurra (pedir permiso) lo hagas después (pedir perdón). En Sql Server tienes los bloques `TRY / CATCH` dónde eventualmente podrías controlar el error y ofrecer un mensaje más elegante al usuario.

Comment: Patricio Moracho Lo que tu dices es lo que quiero hacer pero en MySQL no existe la clausula try catch entonces lo que quiero saber es como se haría.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la sentencia 'SIGNAL SQLSTATE' en los [ procedimientos | funciones | triggers ] en MySQL.

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Minimo 3 caracteres';
```

Cada tipo de error es un numero predefinido por convención, aunque puedes poner el numero que quieras, te dejo una tabla de los códigos de error mas frecuente:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1048 BEGIN /* El parámetro no puede ser nulo. */ END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1050 BEGIN /* La tabla ya existe. */ END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1064 BEGIN /* El parámetro es incorrecto. */ END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1146 BEGIN /* La tabla no existe. */ END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1318 BEGIN /* Número de parámetros incorrecto. */ END;
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE miProcedimiento( arg1 TINYINT(1))
 BEGIN
  IF (arg is null) THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El valor es null';
  ELSE
   ..code      
  END IF;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Esta opción solo funciona para versiones igual o superiores a MySQL 5.5

Te paso el link de la documentación de MySQL: [Aqui](https://vabadus.es/blog/trabajando-con-git-deshacer-un-merge)